# Remote Desktop Connection Password

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is it possible to enable password only for Remote Desktop Connection? I need password since I am connecting from out of network.  But, I don't need password prompt when I am restarting the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different accounts. One with password and the other one without.

Comment: When the computer restarts, it's going to prompt to select user.  I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: No, use instruction from here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx.